# How to refer variable value inside for loop along with incrementing variable name in Bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, unix

We have below variables declared as such

```
CONNECT_ERETAIL1="-h17.XXX.XXX.XX1 -uroot -pXXXXXX"
CONNECT_ERETAIL2="-h17.XXX.XXX.XX2 -uroot -pXXXXXX"

ERETAIL_DB1=/usr01/eretail_db1.txt
ERETAIL_DB2=/usr01/eretail_db2.txt
```

We need to refer them inside for loop

```
for i in 1 2
do
echo $"CONNECT_ERETAIL""$i"
echo $"ERETAIL_DB""$i"
done
```

The expected output is :-

```
-h17.XXX.XXX.XX1 -uroot -pXXXXXX
/usr01/eretail_db1.txt
-h17.XXX.XXX.XX2 -uroot -pXXXXXX
/usr01/eretail_db2.txt
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Try https://shellcheck.net to validate your script.

Comment: Thank you for responding @Jetchisel, However, I do not want to validate my code. I am seeking a solution for the output I expect as shown in the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking after:

```
for i in 1 2; do
    t1="CONNECT_ERETAIL$i"
    t2="ERETAIL_DB$i"
    echo "${!t1}"
    echo "${!t2}"
done
```

You can read more about that kind of parameter expansion [in this manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Also, using all-uppercase variables is discouraged as they may conflict with bash environment variables.

Comment: Thank you so much @Quasimodo that is what I was looking for :)

Comment: Thank you @RavinderSingh13 for the nice words! Glad to help, nitin194.

Comment: can you suggest a better heading for this question? I think it can be asked in a better way

Comment: @nitin194 Maybe "How to expand the variable identified by the expansion of another variable?"

Comment: Yes, that might have been better to ask for, wish I could edit that. Is there a way?